# Foreach System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, foreach, null

I get System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in this:

```
var offeredItems = new List<ulong>(Trade.steamMyOfferedItems);
foreach (var item in offeredItems) {
    Trade.RemoveItem(item);
}
```

What is different than in all such questions is that the exception is in line 3 from this code block. Does it mean that Trade is null? That would be strange because I make this check a few operations earlier:

```
if (Trade != null && Trade.OtherSID == OtherSID) {
    OnTradeMessage(message);
    return;
}
```

The only reason for this would be if Trade was nulled in another thread (and that would be very unecxpected behaviour) in time of 5-10 simple operations, this would be really very strange.

EDIT:

The problem is I can't reproduce this doing the exact same steps. I guess Trade has to be null and it has to be nulled in other thread, there is no other option. Sorry for stupid question.

EDIT2:

If `Trade.RemoveItem` is executed, then `offeredItems` is not empty, hence `Trade` cannot be `null`. In both cases `offeredItems` should contain 1-2 elements. So as far as I know (and understand):

`Trade` is not `null`,
`Trade` is an object of class `Trade`, which has method `RemoveItem` (the exception is thrown exactly at this line: `Trade.RemoveItem(item);`, not in `RemoveItem`,
`RemoveItem` is not `null` delegate (this code works most of the time)

Comment: Do you *have* other threads executing that *could* be setting that to null? At any rate, see the related questions list to the right. There are a million of these questions and the solution is the same. Find out what's null and fix it or validate against it.

Comment: Do you think `item` exist in `Trade`? It might not be found -  My guess

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Are you able to run the code in a debugger so it pauses execution when the exception is thrown? If so, once it pauses, check the value of `Trade` and other relevant information. This should help you determine what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> the exception is in line 3 from this code block
>
> Does it mean that Trade is null?

It *could* mean that. It sounds like one of the following possibilities:

1. `Trade` is `null`.
2. `Trade` is a property whose getter throws a `NullReferenceException`.
3. `RemoveItem` is a `null` delegate.
4. `RemoveItem` throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Why don't you step through the code in a debugger and find out? Also, please see the comments to your question.